# How can I recover a WWW directory and included files in Ubuntu 9.04?

Tags: web-development, documents, ubuntu-9.04

I'm using Ubuntu 9.04 for Drupal development.  This morning I accidentally removed my www folder in directory.  The folder has many of my web development documents.

I just restart my system after it happened, and I installed some recovery software like gpart.  Is there any way to recover my www directory and files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not write your titles in all capital letters

Comment: Caps is for cruise control. :D

Answer (score 4):

At this moment I'd say it very unlikely that you'll be able to recover it. If you'd like to spend some hours trying it, read carefully the ext3 undelete howto and see if ext3grep can help you:

http://www.xs4all.nl/~carlo17/howto/undelete_ext3.html

Power down the machine and use another disk for the operations.

Comment: Hi João Miguel, welcome to Super User. Please note [Are taglines & signatures disallowed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5029/are-taglines-signatures-disallowed) Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

**Unplug** the drive immediately and don't write **anything** to it. Mount it as **read-only** and try to use data-recovery tools to see if you can recover your folder.

Comment: Hai vivin.,

    O God., I just restart after my system when it happens., and i install some recovery software like gpart. is theri any possibilities to recover my www directory and files., bcos its includes more of web development documents.

pls pls pls i'm very afraid about that issue. let me know asap.

Thnaks in Many more advance,

Comment: Well. Gpart is not a recovery utility to begin with. And if the data have been overwritten or something, the data is lost. (I don't know any good recovery software for ext4, there are good utils for XFS, reiserFS and of course NTFS. Next time, consider using a professional filesystem.)

Comment: Without trying to sound unreasonable, this is a good lesson for using source control for your web development, like git or Mercurial.

Comment: is there any possibilities to recover datas asap in ubuntu 9.04.